# What apps can view crash reports on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios

It's cumbersome to sync with iTunes to get a crash report. I'm looking for an app that can view and copy/paste or email crash reports from any other app on my iPhone. I want to see the full stack trace from the crash.

Is there an app for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since iOS 5, you can do this straight from the Settings App. It's located at `Settings > General > About > Diagnostics & Usage > Diagnostics & Usage Data`.

Comment: In iOS 6, tap and hold in a crash report would present a Select All option. In iOS 7, Select All isn't there. If you know how to select all in iOS 7 or later, please comment with a solution. Thanks!